# How to evaluate this triple integral

Tags: integration

I'm having some issues to go on with exercise below

$$\iiint_B z \text{ d}V\ $$

where solid $B$ is in the first octant, bounded by the cylinder $y^2+z^2=1$ and planes $y=x$ and $x=0$ .

Comment: What issues are hindering you?  Are you having difficulty formulating the limits of the nested integrals?  Do you see a connection with a problem you saw previously in class or on this site?

Comment: I've tried to define the limits plotting their axes, but something seems to be messed up once I try @hardmath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. We have that
$$B=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\;:\; 0\leq x\leq  y\leq 1,\ 0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-y^2}\right\}$$
then
$$\iiint_B z \text{ d}V=\int_{y=0}^1\int_{x=0}^y\int_{z=0}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}z\,dz dx dy.$$
Can you take it from here? The final result should be $1/8$.

Another approach is by cross-sections:
$$\iiint_B z \text{ d}V=\int_{t=0}^1t\cdot \mbox{area}(B\cap \{z=t\}) dt=\int_{t=0}^1t\cdot \frac{1-t^2}{2}\, dt=\frac{1}{8}\left[-(1-t^2)^2\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{8}$$
because $B\cap \{z=t\}$ is a right isosceles triangle with a cathetus of length $\sqrt{1-t^2}$.

Comment: Hello @Robert-z, thanks for your assistance, but there's somehow to get 1/8 or 3/8 as result? We were arguing in class about these answers. There's another way to follow, or something that I could forget?

Comment: @Steve Setchus Is it better now?

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks @Robert-z!